# Timestamp Primary key Kudu

Tags: apache, apache-kudu

I am trying to load data into Kudu table through envelope.
One of the primary key column is timestamp.
DDL :
CREATE TABLE BAL (
client_id int
bal_id int,
effective_time timestamp,
prsn_id int,
bal_amount double,
prsn_name string,
PRIMARY KEY (client_id, bal_id, effective_time)
) 
PARTITION BY HASH(client_id) PARTITIONS 8
STORED AS KUDU;

But It is throwing error Java.lang.illelegalArgumentException

So my question is simple - timestamp column could be part of primary key or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly alright to include timestamp as part of primary key.
Please find the code:

```
use ${var:db_name};
CREATE TABLE test (
  table_name STRING NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  table_id BIGINT NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  last_read_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  window STRING NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  ext_gen_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  extract_date timestamp NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  manual_rerun STRING NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
  PRIMARY KEY (table_name, table_id, last_read_timestamp)
)
STORED AS KUDU;
```

*